# How to merge rows in excel according to length of each row(no. of cells having data in a row)

Tags: python, pandas

I extracted data from a pdf using tabula and converted the csv file into an xlsx file.
Following is the excel data:

[image]

Rows have some line items but as the pdf had the decimal part of amounts in the next line ..the excel also has the amount in the next row but I need to merge these rows.
For example the length of the first row is 13
I want to merge the rows below the first row with length 13 until the next row with length 13 and so on...this should go on until I get the word "Total PO" in the second last cell so that further rows do not merge.
I was trying to use pandas to get the list of data and replace the 'nan' which the dataframe shows by blank space so that the length of list does not change and but I am not able to get any further logic to do so.
 this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(r'path.xlsx')
r=len(df.values)
list2=[]
for i in range(1,r):
    list1=df.loc[i].values.tolist()
    #print(list1)
    list2.append(list1)
#print(list2)
list3=[]
new_list1=[]
for new_list in list2:
    print(new_list)
```

This is the answer I got:

```
['ROMO-VAC SET', 'ROMO-VAC', '25-FEB-', '20', '146.72', '142.3184', '2846', '901890', '341.5', '12', nan, '3', '3187.928']
['(14FG)', 'SET (14FG)', '20', nan, nan, nan, '.368', '99', '6', nan, nan, nan, nan]
['ROMO-VAC SET', 'ROMO-VAC', '25-FEB-', '10', '146.72', '142.3184', '1423', '901890', '170.7', '12', nan, '3', '1593.964']
['(16FG)', 'SET (16FG)', '20', nan, nan, nan, '.184', '99', '8', nan, nan, nan, nan]
['RYLES TUBE', 'RYLES TUBE', '25-FEB-', '100', '10.1900', '9.8843', '988.', '9018', '118.6', '12', nan, '3', '1107.04']
['FG-16', 'FG-16', '20', nan, nan, nan, '43', nan, '1', nan, nan, nan, nan]
['VEIN-O-LINE S', 'VEIN-O-LINE', '25-FEB-', '500', '19.36', '18.7792', '9389', '901890', '1126.', '12', nan, '3', '10516.35']
['10CM', 'S 10CM', '20', nan, nan, nan, '.6', '99', '75', nan, nan, nan, nan]
['Total PO Quantity:', '630', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

I tried to replace the 'nan' with blank space with the following code and was able to but how do i again append it to the list in the same order and same format and then put that list in excel again or is there any other approach

```
for j in new_list:
        if type(j)==float:
            j=" "
        print(j)
```

I know this might be confusing but I tried to explain as best as I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
for new_list in list2:
    new_list = [" " if type(x)==float else x for x in new_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[x for x in list2])
df = df.transpose()
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: your method worked but the data is being added  columns wise and not row wise and I still need to know how to merge the data according to my condition

Comment: Thank you..got that but I still need to know how to merge according to the requirement I told above in my question